# SQL server connects after browser restart

Tags: browser, sql-server-2008, ssms

I am using SQL server 2008 trying to connect the server using management studio using ssms with server name including ports and named instance with SQl authentication . Windows firewall is disabled .

I have ports enabled in SQl server manager and browser is running .

Sometimes the connection to the SQL is not possible even if the  port is mentioned . So I restart the browser when this happens and then connection to the server is possible .

Is there any settings to be done so that I can connect server without browser restart?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't turn off the windows firewall.
Please turn on the firewall and add the `sqlservr.exe` file from below path to inbound rule:

```
`%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQL2008\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe`
```